# Version of Package in Xcode Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, swift-package-manager

My SPM detail in Xcode says 12.12.0 of RealmSwift is loaded, but when my app accesses Realm, I get the message that 10.46.0 is available.  Is that just information or do I misunderstand what Xcode says verses what the app is displaying in the console?

I used to load Realm from CocoaPods and so I controlled which version of Realm was in my Project.  But after installing with the SPM, I am not sure how I maintain currency and/or delay updates of the package.

Comment: Try to read the Package.resolved. Could be `./YourApp.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved` in case of simple XcodeProj, I'll let you find it. Could be an issue of RealmSwift that doesn't read correctly the value when using SPM?

Answer (score 0):

Those are different versions of two different things. One is the SDK version, and one is the underlying database version.

It's a bit confusing but if you look a the [SDK Releases](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/releases?page=1), you can see them both. For example here's the current setup for SDK 10.46.0 which uses the underlying core database version 13.26.0

[image]

Here's how to get that info

Looking at the left hand pane in Xcode, there will be two Package Dependencies.

The Realm master->Package shows both the underlying Realm core database version (coreVersion) as well as the current SDK version (cocoaVersion).

[image]

The RealmDatabase->Package just shows the underlying database version. Those should always be the same.

What's showing in your question is the underlying coreDatabase version (12.12) which was from a couple of years ago and went with SDK v10.33.0 (?). If you want to update just do File->Packages->Update To Latest Package Versions (see below), which will update both. (please make a backup before doing that)

But to answer your question - if you don't update the packages, they won't update, so like CocoaPods, you are in control of versioning and only update your SDK when you're ready code-wise to adopt any changes.

[image]